# kohana ---- auto insert

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.3

How to insert same data into database after update in ORM?
For example i have function save() and inside this function i have update and it's working, but i don't know how to make insert with old update data. I mean it should make something like history in database. I only hope you can understand what i mean. Thanks for help.

```
public function save(Validation $validation = NULL)
{
    if ($this->loaded()) {
        // UPDATE TRIGGER

        DB::update($this->_table_name)
            ->set(array('ud_status' => 'D'))
            ->where('ud_status', '=', 'A')
            ->where('ud_uId', '=', $this->ud_uId)
            ->execute($this->_db);

        return false;
    } else {
        // INSERT TRIGGER
        return parent::save($validation);
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW! a long time I do not hear about Kohana...

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = DB::insert('users', array('username', 'password'))->values(array('fred', 'p@5sW0Rd'));
```

https://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/database/query/builder#insert

Comment: I already know about this, but i need to use this function like a trigger in mysql so it should first update and change only status into 'D' values, next should work insert trigger with new data even after using only update in form should add in table new record but still i am not sure how to transfer data from view to model dynamically, but i don't know how. O.o